# equals in java not returning correct value

Tags: java, string

I am writing a simple program in java that compares two files:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Hello{

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{ 
     Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("d.txt"));
     Scanner inFile2 = new Scanner(new File("d2.txt"));
     int i = 0;
     while(inFile.hasNext() || inFile2.hasNext()){
         System.out.println("hello"); 
         String a = (String)inFile.next();
         String b = (String)inFile2.next(); 
         if(a.equals(b)){i=+1;}
     }
     System.out.println(i);

  }
}
```

The two files d and d2 contain the same thing "hello world". However, variable i always returns 1! I tried debugging by printing our the values of the two files and they printed out the same content. Any ideas why it's not comparing correctly?

Comment: You set variable i to 1, what do you expect it to return?

Comment: problem number 1: you never close your Scanner. `inFile.close(); inFile2.close();`

Comment: You probably meant to do i++;

Comment: OTher problem. those .next() functions are going to throw NoSuchElementExceptions if inFile and inFile2 ever have different lengths. Use `while(inFile.hasNext() && inFile2.hasNext()){` instead

Answer (score 3):

i =+ 1 is i = (+1), i.e. assigning the unary + of 1 to i

i += 1 is short-hand for i = i + 1

So you might need to use i+=1 instead of using i=+1

Comment: thanks.. such a small bug I didn't notice

Answer (score 1):

Variable `i` always returns 1 since you assign to it +1:

```
i=+1;
```

Perhaps you want to increment it:

```
i+=1;
```